# Cisco Packet Tracer error UnboundLocalError in python

Tags: python

I am getting an `UnboundLocalError` error when I run a python code that shouldn't result in an error according to most python users. The version of Packet Tracer is 8.0.0 and probably python 2

I was told that globing is not good to use instead I should use functions where I `return` the value.

**Code:**

```
from udp import *
from time import *
from gpio import *


def onUDPReceive(ip, port, data):
    return int(data)
    
def main():
    socket = UDPSocket()
    temp=socket.onReceive(onUDPReceive)
    print(socket.begin(1235))
    
    while True:
        if temp >= 520:#error
            digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
            delay(1000)
            digitalWrite(3, LOW);
            delay(500)
            customWrite(9, 2);
        else:
            digitalWrite(0, LOW);
            customWrite(2, 0);
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

*Error:* `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'temp' referenced before assignment in file main.py on line 15`

**What I have tried:**
I  have tired to `print(temp);`right after `temp=socket.onReceive(onUDPReceive)`, but it still gives me the same error

When adding

```
try:
        print(temp);
```

`ParseError: bad input in file main.py on line 17`

**The system:**
[image: System]

**Image of code**

[image]

Comment: make sure temp is initialized properly try printing the value of temp

Comment: I have tried to print the value, but it gives me the same error message

Comment: yeah that means something gone wrong while initializing temp variable you can put that in try catch block to see what's the error

Comment: How would I do that because when I use `try`I get bad input

Comment: can you add the output of try catch block

Comment: Can you check again have tried adding the try block

Comment: Maybe he should stick to globing if this doesnt work, he even stats that it was fine with globing

Comment: I guess `onUDPReceive` is a callback function and is called asynchronously, i.e. doesn’t return a value. Using globals would work but yes isn’t desirable. The other approach would be to put the callback function in a class instance which can store the received value and/or process it.